# Traverse a type generated by Azure Storage type provider in F#

Tags: azure, f#, functional-programming, type-providers

I am trying to get my head around type providers in F# and what they can be used for. I have the following problem:

I have a series of JSON objects in Azure Blob Storage stored as follows:

```
container/YYYY/MM/DD/file.json
```

I can easily navigate to a specific file for a given date using a type provider. For example, I can access the JSON object as a string for the 5th of May as

```
type Azure = AzureTypeProvider<"ConnectionString">
let containers  = Azure.Containers.``container``.``2017/``.``05/``.``05/``.``file.json``.Read()
```

How can I take a user input date string, say "2017-05-05" and get the corresponding JSON object in a type safe way? Should I even be using type providers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're coming up against a common "issue" with the nature of many TPs, particularly ones that offer a schema against actual data - because it blends the line between data and types, you need to be aware of when you're working in a mode that works well with static types (i.e. you know at compile time the schema of the blob containers you're working with), or working in a way that's inherently dynamic.

You have a few options here.

1. Fall back to the "native" .NET SDK. Every blob / container has associated `AsCloudBlob()` or `AsCloudContainer()` methods, so you can use the TP for the bits that you *do* know e.g container name, maybe top level folders etc., and then fall back to the native SDK for the weakly-typed bits.
2. Since the latest release of the TP, there's now support for programmatic access in a couple of ways: -

   - You can use indexers to get an unsafe handle to a blob e.g. `let blob = Azure.Containers.container.["2017/05/05/file.json"]`. There's no guarantee that the blob exists, so you need to check that yourself etc.
   - You can use the `TryGetBlockBlob()` method, which returns a `blob option async` - behind the scenes, it will do a check if the blob exists or not, and then return either None, or Some blob.

You can see more examples of all of these alternatives [here](http://fsprojects.github.io/AzureStorageTypeProvider/blobs.html#Programmatic-access).

3. If you know up-front the full path you're working with (at compile time - perhaps some well-know paths etc.), you can also use the [offline support](http://fsprojects.github.io/AzureStorageTypeProvider/blobs.html#Offline-development) in the TP to create an explicit blob schema at compile time without needing a real storage account.